# Type of variable used in macro polynomial?

Tags: expansion, polynomials

I would like to use polynomial macro, just with the standard way.
But the coefficients of the polynom are generated by `\FPeval` or `\pgfmathrandominteger` commands => the result of polynomial isn't the expected one ...

```
\begin{document}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\VRcoeffa}{-5}{-1}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\VRcoeffb}{-5}{-1}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\VRcoeffc}{-5}{-1}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\VRcoeffd}{-5}{-1}

$f(x)=\polynomial[reciprocal]{\VRcoeffa,\VRcoeffb,\VRcoeffc,\VRcoeffd}$\par

\FPeval\VRcoeffa{(0-1)}     \FPclip\VRcoeffa{\VRcoeffa}
\FPeval\VRcoeffb{(0-3)}     \FPclip\VRcoeffb{\VRcoeffb}
\FPeval\VRcoeffc{(0)}       \FPclip\VRcoeffc{\VRcoeffc}
\FPeval\VRcoeffd{(0-12)}    \FPclip\VRcoeffd{\VRcoeffd}
\FPeval\VRcoeffe{(1)}       \FPclip\VRcoeffe{\VRcoeffe}
\FPeval\VRcoefff{(0-1)}     \FPclip\VRcoefff{\VRcoefff}

$f(x)=\polynomial[reciprocal]{%
\VRcoeffa,%
\VRcoeffb,%
\VRcoeffc,%
\VRcoeffd,%
\VRcoeffe,%
\VRcoefff%
}$
\par
$\polynomial[reciprocal]{-1,-3,0,-12,1,-1}$

\end{document}
```

I suspect a managment of type of variable I've no idea about with LaTeX (I'm not very used to LaTeX ... but I'm trying ;o).
Thanks in advance for your help !

**** EDIT ****

This is unrelated to `pgfmath.`  Looks like an expansion issue.  Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polynomial}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vl}{-3}

$\polynomial[reciprocal]{1,\vl}$

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

instead of $x-3$

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Could you complete the example to include a documenclass (`article` is fine) and the necessary packages? And what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I added a MWE to OP's post.

Comment: This is clearly a bug. @JPi, I think you are right that it has to do with expansion. The coefficient `\vl` is not expanded before the check of `-`. I will dig into the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments this is a bug due to that the coefficient `\vl` in the MWE is not expanded before the check of `-`. Try to include the code from `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (including these commands) after `\usepackage{polynomial}` in the preamble as in the modified MWE below. (I also removed the `[resiprocal]` since it is irrelevant).

Please let me know if this work so I can upload a corrected version to CTAN (after re-learning how to pack it correctly:).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polynomial}
\makeatletter
\def\shpol@getcoeff#1{% Parse the coeffs and store in #1-vars
  \shpol@numcoeff=0%
  \@for\shpol@coeff:=#1\do{%
    \advance\shpol@numcoeff by 1\relax%
    \expandafter\edef\csname shpol@coeff\romannumeral\shpol@numcoeff\endcsname{\shpol@coeff}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vl}{-3}

$\polynomial{1,\vl,-4}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As pointed out by B.Gravouil there is a problem with passing expanded versions of some commands. For example `\dfrac` and `\tfrac` from the Ams-packets does not work with this fix. However, `\frac` works as expected and a workaround in this case is to use `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` versions of it.

```
\newcommand{\vl}{-3}
\newcommand{\fl}{\frac{2}{3}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\polynomial{1,\vl,\frac{2}{3}}$
\item $\displaystyle\polynomial{1,\vl,\frac{2}{3}}$
\item $\polynomial{1,\vl,\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}}$
\item $\polynomial{1,\fl,\frac{2}{3}}$
\item $\displaystyle\polynomial{1,\fl,\frac{2}{3}}$
\item $\polynomial{1,\fl,\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}}$
\item $\polynomialfrac{1,2,3}{2,\vl,4}$
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: works for me....  you don't need the curlies around \vl.

Comment: @JPi I removed them. They where leftovers from testing.

Comment: @B.Gravouil I have added a workaround for the `\dfrac` case.