# Use of polynomial command with an argument defined by \dfrac{2]{3} for example

Tags: polynomials

This question is the following of this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354021/type-of-variable-used-in-macro-polynomial). The solution worked very well (Thanks so much JPI !) but it remains another request : with the previous code (without the 1st solution by JPI) I could use polynomial command with `\dfrac{2}{3}` as one of the arguments. And it worked ! Now (with the JPI's solution) it doesn't. Question : is there a solution to both requirements ?
The following (without JPI's code) is the code leading to the following result :

```
\FPeval\VRcoeffa{(0-1)}     \FPclip\VRcoeffa{\VRcoeffa}
\FPeval\VRcoeffb{(8/3)}     \FPclip\VRcoeffb{\VRcoeffb}
\FPeval\VRcoeffc{(0)}       \FPclip\VRcoeffc{\VRcoeffc}
\FPeval\VRcoeffd{(0-12)}    \FPclip\VRcoeffd{\VRcoeffd}
\FPeval\VRcoeffe{(1)}       \FPclip\VRcoeffe{\VRcoeffe}
\FPeval\VRcoefff{(0-1)}     \FPclip\VRcoefff{\VRcoefff}
\FPset\toto{\dfrac{2}{3}}

$f(x)=\polynomial[reciprocal]{%
\VRcoeffa,%
\dfrac{2}{3},%
\VRcoeffc,%
\VRcoeffd,%
\VRcoeffe,%
\VRcoefff%
}$
```

The result is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps with `\noexpand`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polynomial,amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\shpol@getcoeff#1{% Parse the coeffs and store in #1-vars
  \shpol@numcoeff=0%
  \@for\shpol@coeff:=#1\do{%
    \advance\shpol@numcoeff by 1\relax%
    \expandafter\edef\csname shpol@coeff\romannumeral\shpol@numcoeff\endcsname{\shpol@coeff}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vl}{-3}

$\polynomial{1,\vl,-4}$

$\polynomial{1,\vl,-\noexpand\dfrac{4}{3}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was expecting ! Thanks ! Is it requesting a modification of the polynomial command ?

Comment: @B.Gravouil I used the code that JPI had provided, and worked in that context.  Whether the author of `polynomial` would like to offer such an option, I cannot say, but it is clear he intended the arguments to be direct numbers and not macros.  Perhaps you could email the author of `polynomial` if you are seeking something more official.